# how can change language of an application into english from Chinese

Tags: windows, translation

I have an Application for windows which is written in Chinese that I need to change it into english.  The application has no option to change the language so I'm wondering if it would be possible to do so?

The application I am trying to change is meant for communication with ARM 51 MCU board.

Please let me know if this can be done.

If it is possible I have a translator who can translate between Chinese and English for the application.

Comment: **You're unclear. What do you mean the application is written in Chinese? I've never seen a Chinese compiler for Windows.** C++ and million variants maybe, but never Chinese. Please be more precise our your question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: You can use a resource editor to modify the strings stored in the binary.